# Swift: Variable of Optional Dictionary inside Class: Shows Brackets in Output

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type, optional-parameters, square-bracket

I would like to make an Optional Dictionary Variable inside of a Class so that when I create an instance I don't HAVE to add that argument...

example

```
class Stuff {
     var dictionary: [String: Double]?
     init(dictionary: [String:Double]?=["":0]){
}
}
var instance1    = Stuff(dictionary:["length":1.5])
var array: [Stuff] = [instance1, instance2]

let arraySet = (array[indexPath.row])
let X = arraySet.dictionary!

cell.Label.text = "\(X)"
```

This works but when i assign it to a cell.label.text the output shows Brackets...

"[length:1.5]"

How can i get rid of the brackets???

Comment: how do you *assign* the dictionary to the label?

Comment: Please show the line of code where the `text` property of the label is set `cell.label.text = ??`

Comment: You're assigning the *description* of the dictionary which is the string representation like in a `print` statement. A dictionary is a collection object with key/value pairs. Maybe a different object or objects is more suitable for your purpose

Answer (score 2):

It's quite complicated to get rid of the brackets, because the key/value pair must be extracted out of the dictionary:

```
class Stuff {
  var dictionary: [String: Double]?
  init(dictionary: [String:Double]?=["":0.0]){
    self.dictionary = dictionary
  }
}


 let instance = Stuff(dictionary:["length":1.5])
 if let dict = instance.dictionary where dict.count > 0 {
   let key = dict.keys.first!
   let value = dict[key]!
   label.text = "\(key) : \(value)"
 }
```

If you create the dictionary with non-optional literals, consider to declare the variable `dictionary` as non-optional